# Is it possible to customize UINavigationBar by protocol?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, protocols

I want to customize UINavigationBar for some view controllers. For some reasons, I **cannot** just simply extend UIViewController. So I was trying to do it by a protocol.

What I have tried:

```
protocol TransparentNavigationBarProtocol {
    func makeNavigationBarTransparent()
}

extension TransparentNavigationBarProtocol where Self: UIViewController {

    func makeNavigationBarTransparent() {
        if let navController = navigationController {
            navController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
            navController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
            navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
            navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent
            navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
            navController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
        }
    }

}
```

I added some breakpoints which show the function had been called successfully but the navigationBar didn't change. So I was wondering is it possible to achieve this by protocols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Xcode11, you need set a image, not nil

Also, in your viewcontroller's viewWillAppear, you need call makeNavigationBarTransparent()

```
func makeNavigationBarTransparent() {
    if let navController = navigationController {
        navController.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navController.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navController.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 74/255, green: 74/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)
        navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
        navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 74/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)]
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    makeNavigationBarTransparent()
}
```